# Want to display tags with click event javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im new to javascript so if my code isn't the best i apologise in advance! Im trying to display the tags when a certain name is clicked with the click event (eventListener), but I have no idea how! I tried writing the code how I want it, but now im stuck. I want the tags to be displayed in the aside 1 if the name is clicked. Any help is appreciated!

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);

const cardsContainer = document.querySelector("#cards")
const birdNames = ["Koolmees", "Specht", "kerkuil"]
const birdImages = ["https://www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg?itok=arfFjeTb&c=312068de040ea85bb4eb43164e28b3b2", "https://www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg", "https://www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg"]
const birds = [
    { name: "Koolmees", image: "https://www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg?itok=arfFjeTb&c=312068de040ea85bb4eb43164e28b3b2", tag:"rotterdam, koolmees, kleine vogel" },
    { name: "specht", image: "https://www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg" },
    { name: "kerkuil", image: "https://www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg" }
]
const Birdtags = ["rotterdam, koolmees, kleine vogel", "specht, nijmegen, kleine vogel", "uil, eindhoven, grote vogel, roofvogel"]
let Field;
let target;


function init()
{
    //Click handler for every card
    Field = document.getElementById('field');
    Field.addEventListener('click', playingFieldClickHandler);

    //starting
    addCard();

    //Listen to input of chosen name by user
    let playForm = document.getElementById('form');
    playForm.addEventListener('submit', formSubmitHandler);

}


function addCard(birdImage, birdName){
    const cardDiv = document.createElement("flex-item")
    cardDiv.classList.add("card")
    cardsContainer.appendChild(cardDiv)

    const img = document.createElement("img")
    img.src = birdImage
    cardDiv.appendChild(img)

    const nameDiv = document.createElement("div")
    nameDiv.innerText = birdName
    cardDiv.appendChild(nameDiv)
}

function playingFieldClickHandler(e)
{
   /** what do I put here???*/
}

function formSubmitHandler(e)
{
    //Prevent default form submit
    e.preventDefault();


    //If the value is the right one, you won!
    if (birdNames === "koolmees") {
        /** display tags */
    } else if (birdNames === "specht") {
        /** display tags */
    }
    else if (birdNames === "kerkuil") {
        /** display tags */
    }
}

function addCards(){
    for(let i = 0; i<birdNames.length; i++){
        addCard(birdImages[i], birdNames[i])
    }
}

addCards()
```

```css
flex-container {
    /* We first create a flex layout context */
    display: flex;

    /* Then we define the flow direction
       and if we allow the items to wrap
     * Remember this is the same as:
     * flex-direction: row;
     * flex-wrap: wrap;
     */
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
    justify-content: space-around;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

flex-item {
    background: #ABEBC6;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #A2D9CE;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: #1565C0;
}


wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

wrapper > * {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

header {
    background: #DAF7A6;
}

footer {
    background: #28B463;
}

main {
    text-align: left;
    background: #A2D9CE;
}

aside {
    background: #28B463;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    main    { flex: 3 0px; }
    aside   { order: 1; }
    main    { order: 2; }
    footer  { order: 3; }
}

body {
    width: 100%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav {
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    nav li:last-of-type a {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}

p1 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}

p2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p3 {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}

img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <title>Test week 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<wrapper>
    <header><p1>Vogel magazine voor vogelspotters!</p1></header>
    <main>
        <flex-container id="cards">


        </flex-container>
    </main>
    <aside>Aside 1</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</wrapper>

<script src="js/DOM4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you made custom HTML elements?

Comment: to test out my css

Comment: `document.getElementById('field');` ~ there is no element with id `field`

Comment: @MichVDW *to test out my css* --- what does that mean 

Comment: nor is there a form

Comment: There is no such HTML element as `wrapper`

Comment: Within the `init` function you call `addCard();` but with no arguments yet the function expects 2 arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly I modified the HTML structure a little as there were errors with the markup, possibly screwed up your CSS and changed the multiple source arrays for a single `Object literal` but you should be able to adapt the following to suit your needs. I made this do what I thought you were trying to do.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);

const cardsContainer = document.querySelector('#cards');
const aside = document.querySelector('#wrapper aside');

/*
  If you re-structure your data into a single Object literal
  you will, I think, find less issues with maintaining several
  arrays and ensuring they all have the same number of items etc

  This sort of data structure can easily be created in the form of
  JSON data from a database query!

  Each sub-object ( aka - Bird ) can be extended easily to have additional
  properties quite easily, especially if database driven.

  If you remove, from the img src, the `scheme` you can generally get the image to download
  using the same scheme as the parent page. One day ALL websites will be hosted on SSL
  so this will be redundant but in the meantime this might help prevent warnings

*/
const birds={
  'Koolmees':{
    src:'//www.natuurpunt.be/sites/default/files/styles/content-wide/public/koolmees_fr_van_bauwel.jpg',
    tags:'rotterdam, koolmees, kleine vogel'
  },
  'Specht':{
    src:'//www.buitenleven.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/grote-bonte-specht.jpg',
    tags:'specht, nijmegen, kleine vogel'
  },
  'kerkuil':{
    src:'//www.vogelhuisjes.nl/media/wysiwyg/vogels-in-de-tuin/vogels-in-nederland/xkerkuil.jpg.pagespeed.ic.8a2v4rM0Z3.jpg',
    tags:'uil, eindhoven, grote vogel, roofvogel'
  }
};


/*
  It is unclear from the code what you hope to do with the `submithandler`
  especially given that there is no form ( or was no form ) so I guessed
  that you were hoping to do something similar to what this method does..

  if there is no `figcaption` below the image it will add the caption and
  assign the `tags` text which is assigned to the image as a dataset attribute
*/
const clickhandler=function(e){
  let fig=e.target.parentNode.querySelector('figcaption');
  if( fig==null ){
    fig=document.createElement('figcaption');
    fig.textContent=this.dataset.tags
    e.target.parentNode.appendChild( fig );
  }else{
    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(fig)
  }
  aside.textContent=fig==null ? '' : this.dataset.tags;
}






function init(){

  /* the first does nothing, the 2nd has errors and the 3rd is incomplete...

  //Click handler for every card
  document.getElementById('field').addEventListener('click', playingFieldClickHandler);

  //starting
  //addCard(src,name,desc);

  //Listen to input of chosen name by user
  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', formSubmitHandler);
  */

  document.getElementById('cards').querySelectorAll('.card').forEach( card => {
    card.addEventListener('click',clickhandler );
  });
}


function addCard(birdImage, birdName, birdTags){// now takes 3 arguments
  let item = document.createElement('flex-item');
    item.classList.add('card');
    item.dataset.tags=birdTags; //assign the tags as a dataset atttribute
  cardsContainer.appendChild(item)

  let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = birdImage;
    img.title=birdTags; //  tags also assigned for the img title
  item.appendChild(img)

  let name = document.createElement('div')
    name.innerText = birdName
  item.appendChild(name)
}




/**********************************************************
  Unclear how these two functions are really to be used
  - unchanged
*/
function playingFieldClickHandler(e)
{
   /** what do I put here???*/
}
function formSubmitHandler(e)
{
  //Prevent default form submit
  e.preventDefault();

  //If the value is the right one, you won!
  if (birdNames === "koolmees") {
    /** display tags */
  } else if (birdNames === "specht") {
    /** display tags */
  }
  else if (birdNames === "kerkuil") {
    /** display tags */
  }
}







/*
  With the new data structure a new approach to iterating through the 
  data is required. Using the `object.keys` method allows us to quickly
  iterate through each sub-object. The `key` is the bird name.
*/
function addCards(){
  Object.keys( birds ).forEach( key => {
    let bird=birds[ key ];
    addCard( bird.src, key, bird.tags )
  })
}

addCards()
```

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

flex-container {
  /* We first create a flex layout context */
  display: flex;

  /*    Then we define the flow direction
   *  and if we allow the items to wrap
   *    Remember this is the same as:
   *    flex-direction: row;
   *    flex-wrap: wrap;
  */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex:10;
  margin:auto;

  /* Then we define how is distributed the remaining space */
  justify-content: space-around;

  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
flex-container figcaption{
  font-size:1rem;
  line-height:1rem;
  color:white;
}

flex-item {
  background: #ABEBC6;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height:250px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  background: #A2D9CE;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #1565C0;
}


#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex:10;

  flex-direction:column;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;

  min-height:100vh;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
}
#wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
header {
  background: #DAF7A6;
  flex:2!important;
  order:1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
footer {
  background: #28B463;
  flex:1!important;
  order:3;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
main {
  text-align: left;
  background: #A2D9CE;
  flex:50!important;
  order:2;
}
aside {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background: #28B463;
  flex:1;
  margin:auto;
  max-height:2rem;
  width:100%;
  padding:0!important;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  aside   { order: 1; }
  main    { order: 2; }
  footer  { order: 3; }
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  nav li:last-of-type a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}

p1 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}
p2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p3 {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
}
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'><!-- There is no HTML element `wrapper` -->
    <header><p1>Vogel magazine voor vogelspotters!</p1></header>
    <main>
      <flex-container id="cards"></flex-container><!-- unusual to assign custom elements without accompanying javascript/css -->
    </main>
    <aside>Aside 1</aside>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: you have no idea how much you helped me, thanks!

Comment: perhaps you should consider accepting the answer?!